# Android AsyncTask case to freeze application on phone call received

Tags: android

My android application communicate with web services to download and upload data using AsyncTask. If i receive phone call during communication the application hanged up, else every thing is ok. how i can handle this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You're probably getting some exception ... Can you post some code and logcat output with that exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a service for these kinds of tasks, for fully understanding what happens it is better to take a look at Android's activity life-cycle:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/